# I was refused as standar visitor visa - can I apply for short term study visa for summer school?

Tags: visas, uk

Last year, I applied for a standard visitor visa and it was refused due to the incomplete document evidence. Now I want to apply for a short term study visa through my university. Can I apply, even after the standard visa refusal?

Comment: You can always _apply_, but unless you can fix the problems that led to the earlier application being rejected, it is not likely that the new one will be successful.